# Database with antigens and current vaccines

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, database, covid-19, sars-cov-2

I am seeking virological databases focussing on:

- vaccines
- antibody interactions
- host receptors.

Preferably the data base will host multiple strains/samples of a given virus samples.

Any assistance would be welcome.

Comment: Hi MniNi, could you tell us what viruses you are interested in?

Comment: Anything that is parse-able data, has documented binding site or vaccine, best both. I need real data in some data analysis I want to try on, with sequential substituted correlation. (Having substituents on certain shapes of chain, and correlating differences to differences in those substituents)

Comment: Hey ya, note you can [edit] the question and add more details (as those you wrote in the comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given "any virus will do", the viruses that are "head and shoulders" above the rest in terms of volumes of data are HIV and influenza.

The influenza database is [here](https://www.fludb.org/brc/home.spg?decorator=influenza)

The influenza viral spike that attaches to the cell receptor is the HA protein – hemagglutinin. The cell receptor is sialic acid – a small sugar that is attached to many different proteins on the cell surface. You can of course simply search PDB for HA or else Genbank.

Comment: Ouch, I was abuncted by the goverment again, so I think somebody took the best from influenza vaccine technique and applied it to corona like I wanted.